# NSTextView I think each article has a UndoManager

Tags: macos, nstextview

Edit and save articles in my MacOS application with NSTextView.

Every time I use the same NSTextView object, I delete all the actions every time I read a new article.

```
NSTextView.undoManager?.removeAllActions();
```

But now I have a new idea. I want to be able to have a UndoManager in each article. When I switch the article, the UndoManager object can save the operation of the corresponding article, and I will still be able to execute undo and redo when I edit the document next time.

I tried to create a new UndoManager, but found that it was a read-only object, and I could not change it.

Will my design be reasonable and what can I do to realize my idea of saving UndoManager?

Comment: Why are you using the same NSTextView? Why not just swap in a new NSTextView when you switch to a new article?

Comment: @NimaYousefi The same NSTextView is well managed, and if every article has a view, this will take up more resources. I hope to control it in this respect.

Comment: Do you want to store the undo actions on disk or do you want to store the undo actions while the app is running? You can replace the undo manager in `NSTextViewDelegate` method `undoManager(for:)`.

Comment: @Willeke It's useful for me, thank you.

Comment: @Simon did that work for you? I've been trying the same thing to no avail.